# Default error handler for node express

Tags: node.js, express, error-handling

I've read the [error handling guidance](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html) given for the [`express`](https://expressjs.com/) module, but would like to dig a little deeper and see exactly what the default error handler in `express` actually does (and hence what my custom error handler should and shouldn't do, if it can pass on some of the basic error handling procedure on to the default handler).  It may just be showing my ignorance, but I can't for the life of me find where the default error handler is actually defined in the [`express` source code](https://github.com/expressjs/express).  Please can someone help me out here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure the default handler just logs to stderr.  Look at the logerror function and how it's used in the "finalhandler".

https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/application.js

Comment: it must surely do more than just logging?  According to the guidance I linked to in my OP, "the Express default error handler closes the connection and fails the request".  Where is that happening?

Comment: I can't look at it right now, but probably in that finalhandler module I mentioned

Comment: aah, OK, I see.